# Can't fix modal height in Strict Mode, is Quirks Mode really that bad?

Tags: css, html, quirks-mode

I'm a back-end dev working on an independent project, so please excuse any lack of knowledge that might follow. I'm using a free and open source admin-panel template called AdminLTE, and a bunch of modals as part of it. I've been working on it for a while now and everything was fine, except I didn't notice that a doctype wasn't declared. Using the standard and (as far as I know) heavily recommended html5 strict mode `<!DOCTYPE html>` all of my modals completely break and overflow their bounds.

Like I said, I'm a back-end developer and I just don't see the light at the end of this tunnel, so my question is: **Is quirks mode really that bad?** I've tested my page on latest Chrome, Mozilla as well as whatever Samsung uses on the latest Android and everything works fine and identically on all of them.

I'll attach my specific problem here however since that's against the rules, the main question here is whether quirks mode is still considered bad practice in 2016. I realize there's dozens of posts on this topic everywhere but none of them are very new and we've slowly surpassed Windows XP & old versions of IE, I feel like the arguments might differ.

Modal looks like this, `admins-modal-contentdiv` is filled using either jQuery's `load()` or `html()`if POST is needed.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="admins-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog c-modal-wrapper">
    <div class="modal-content bg-black" >
        <div id="admins-modal-content">
            <div class="c-modal-topbar">
                <h4>Admins</h4>
            </div>

            <div id="admins-modal-contentdiv" class="c-modal-content">

            </div>

            <div class="c-modal-bottombar">
                <a class="btn btn-app" onclick="$('#admins-modal').modal('toggle');">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Back
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal  -->
```

Relevant CSS looks like this

```
.c-modal-wrapper{
    height:80%;
}

.c-modal-topbar{
    font-weight:bold;
    padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    width:95%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

}

.c-modal-content{
    overflow-y:auto;
    height:65%;
    width:100%;
}

.c-modal-bottombar{

}
```

No DOCTYPE
[image]

With `<!DOCTYPE html>`
[image]

At this point I feel like giving up and just going with quirks mode, but since I want to rely on this template / modal usage style for future projects, I'd like to stick to standards so it doesn't end up broken eventually. I've invested hundreds of hours of work into this and I'm scared it's all going to waste.

If you have some free time and would like to have a look, you can check out an example page showing the issue [HERE](http://hosting.r4ge.ro/test.php), just click on "Show Modal". An example of it working as expected, without any doctype declaration, is [HERE](http://hosting.r4ge.ro/test2.php). The pages are identical except for the doctype declaration, both include the same CSS and JS files.

Sorry again for breaking the rules, I have nowhere else to turn to. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Your posted CSS does not convey the result you're showing in the images. Because the CSS you show works as intended. The overflow you're showing is due to something else, so unless you can create an actual example showing the problem, we're not going to be able to help. However, getting a modal to keep within the viewable area boundaries is not difficult.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I've copied everything straight off the website, and adding/removing the doctype does exactly as in the images. The example is available on the test account I provided however I'll make a directly linkable example now to make it easier.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I've updated the question adding the new easy to access example. http://hosting.r4ge.ro/test.php

Comment: This seems to be some sort of magical thinking. "i change quickly/strict mode, things break. thus strict mode is bad/not useful". The hidden aspect here is that simply behavior *changes* and you need to figure out how to achieve the desired results in the new environment, which is entirely possible. Quirks mode exists for backwards compatibility. If you don't want to change anything and keep an old application running, then it's fulfilling its purpose. If you actually want to write modern code that delivers consistent behavior across browsers, then it's the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @the8472 to be honest I mostly added that part to not make this a completely specific "fix this for me" question. I know quirks is the polar opposite of what I need since I'm basically creating a new website and asking about using a backwards-compatibility feature. I fully understand why the problem is there however I have no idea what's causing it or even where to start looking.

Comment: well, then your question doesn't make sense. if you're building up a new website from scratch then quirks mode is not involved and you would be assembling your graphical building blocks/styles incrementally. so any question you would ask would not relate to quirks mode at all.

Comment: @the8472 I've given a bit more detail in a comment on the answer below. I'm basically clueless when it comes to proper HTML/CSS, have started development a long time ago without noticing the missing doctype. Now the whole interface and website design relies on the use of stacking modals. I'm basically a back-end only dev heavily invested in a project and I need someone to point me in the right direction, because all I can do now is trial and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I've managed to fix my particular issue.

What was happening is the modal's content was overflowing it's parent's set height. For some reason in Quirks Mode this height was respected. I'm still not sure what caused this to happen, however setting `height:100%` on all parents before the overflowing content (partially) fixed the issue.

I removed the height from the parents in the first place to make the black background stretch only until the footer's end, however by forcing the `100%` height, some extra empty space appeared under my footer, aka the `c-modal-bottombar` class. This is because I've not forced the footer to the bottom of the div in the first place. Even if I did, the result would've been ugly since the content won't stretch to fill the gap.

If anyone finds themselves in a similar situation, well, you can't do it this way if you have variable sized headers/footers.

The way I ended up making it look like I wanted is by redrawing the entire modal, like this.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="admins-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog c-modal-wrapper">
        <div class="c-modal-topbar bg-black">
            <div class="c-modal-topbar-content">
                <h4>Admins</h4>
                To add a new admin, search for a player in 'Manage Players' and edit his rank.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="admins-modal-contentdiv" class="modal-content bg-black c-modal-content">
        </div>

        <div class="c-modal-bottombar bg-black">
            <a class="btn btn-app" onclick="$('#admins-modal').modal('toggle');">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Back
            </a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal needs to be above adminranks for stacking modals to work -->
```

Some useless divs were removed, their classes merged into one

```
.c-modal-wrapper{
    height:80%;
}

.c-modal-testing{
    height:100%;
}

.c-modal-topbar{
    width:100%;
}

.c-modal-topbar-content{
    width:95%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.c-modal-content{
    overflow-y:auto;
    height:65%;
    width:100%;
}

.c-modal-bottombar{

}
```

Although it's unlikely, I hope this will help at least one other person, so the time of people who read this and the ones who answered isn't wasted.

Thank you again for not downvoting me to oblivion(or locking my q).

Answer (score 2):

The single biggest difference between standards mode and quirks mode is the box model. It sounds like this is what is biting you and breaking your modals when you switch to standards mode.

The good news is that this particular issue is easily dealt with in CSS. There is a standard CSS property that allows you to switch the box model so you can having it work in the quirks mode way even when you are in standards mode.

All you need to so to activate this is this:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Add this style to your stylesheet so that it affects any element you need to. This could just be your modals, or it could be your entire page.

> so my question is: Is quirks mode really that bad?

Well, as you can see from the above, the main difference is well defined and can be switched in either mode. So in that respect, no it isn't.

Recent versions of all the major browsers do treat quirks mode pretty much the same because it's been standardized. It's not perfect, but it is acceptable.

However, quirks mode does have other implications, particularly with older browsers. For example, anyone using IE10 or older will not only get the quirks mode box model, they'll also get a lot of other browser features disabled as Quirks mode in older IE versions is actually an IE5 compatibility mode. IE11 supports this mode and a second quirks mode that changes the box model but doesn't break everything else. It's not always easy to know which one you're going to get though.

People do still use these older IE versions, so what this means is that if your site uses quirks mode, there will be some users of your site who will get a very very bad experience.

Older versions of other browsers may also do similar things.

The thing with quirks mode is that it kinda lives up to its name -- there are quirks, and if your site is using it then you make life harder for yourself because you never really know when you're going to be caught out by them. And when the switch to standards mode is so easy, it seems difficult to justify why anyone would use it. Maybe if you're maintaining an old system, but certainly not for new code.

Comment: I've read a lot about Quirks Mode and how IE 6 to 8 emulated 5.5 for it, every other IE emulating version-1 after that. Would you say this is an acceptable fix to my problem, compatibility and future maintainability-wise?

Comment: The acceptable fix is to use standards mode, and `box-sizing:border-box`. I would avoid quirks mode if you can (and it is easy to avoid with `box-sizing`), and definitely avoid IE's other compatibility modes because they really are awful (even if you do think you need to use them, there are some known bugs that make them practically worthless in my opinion).

Comment: Well, I tried it out however it won't work. First tried applying the property to the `.modal` class, then added `html {  box-sizing: border-box;}` but it still won't work. (have a look http://hosting.r4ge.ro/test.php)

Comment: Okay. Well you would need to use the star selector - `* {box-sizing:border-box;}` rather than `html {...}` because box-sizing doesn't get inherited down the tree. However, I notice that you're using Boostrap, which actually already includes this, so you should in fact be okay with this. That means you're being caught out by one of the other quirks of quirks mode, and I'll need to dig a bit deeper to find it. Unfortunately, you've caught me at the end of my day, so I'm unlikely to have time to help much more. I will let you know if I spot anything for you though.

Comment: It's okay, I'll keep trying to figure it out, the problem is that for me it's mostly trial and error as well as blind searching since most of this stuff is completely unknown to me. I've started development on an earlier version of the same template that either didn't contain the doctype declaration, or I removed it unknowingly. Since the new version doesn't contain modal demos anymore, I'm thinking the template's dev couldn't figure it out either. I appreciate the help, have a nice night.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two CSS-rules:

```
#serverconsole-modal-content {
  height: 40em;
}
.c-modal-bottombar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

That limits the length of the modal, and positions the bottom-bar at the actual bottom of the modal.

Comment: I've tried applying this to the full website but it looks a bit botched(http://i.imgur.com/WIbhZm1.png). It's a lot worse on my phone, so it's not responsive. I'd like to keep it in percentages, since not all modals have only text content.

Comment: Well, it seems that the `.c-modal-bottombar` CSS is not needed for the full content, then - try without. And if it's not responsive, add @media-rules to make it responsive. % won't work, else I would use that.